# Hibernate Interceptor onSave and onLoad methods returns null

Tags: hibernate

I override Hibernate EmptyInterceptor to capture some property fields to do some decorations.

**public class MyEntityInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor** I need to access the

fields when before save and when reading. My onSave and onLoad methods are as below. But my

entity fields returns null. Please let me know your feedback and what am I missing here?

```
public boolean onLoad(Object entity,Serializable id, Object[] state,String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)
        throws CallbackException{

    Persistable entity = (Persistable) entity;
    System.out.println("===============>"+entity.getCreatedBy());//returns null
    return true;
}



public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {

    if (entity instanceof IPersistable) {
        IPersistable entity = (IPersistable) entity;
        System.out.println("Created By=================>"+((IPersistable) entity).getCreatedBy());//Returns null

    }

    return (true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onLoad method called just before an object is initialized.Refer the API.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html. Entity will be an

empty uninitialized instance of the class. This is the reason that you get null output. The way you

capture properties is incorrect. Object[] state,String[] propertyNames are the key

parameters should use if you want to deal with passing parameters. The state comes with the

list of values and property names represent the list of fields. Please iterate state[] array ,

then you will the expected values. Let me know if you need further assistance.